# Negative gradient graphs

Tags: experimental-chemistry

So basically I have a graph of Absorbance on y-axis against Time on x-axis and it is a negative curve. So this will give me a negative slope gradient. My question is how to reason the negative gradient. Do I write down the rate of concentration as a negative value and just reason it by saying that by being negative it means that the concentration is decreasing?

Comment: Welll, if you have reaction and check out for the right wavelength... But you didn't tell it in your post.

Comment: The question may be rather naive but doesn't deserve to be down voted. What does the wavelength have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Beer's law tells us that the absorption is the product of path length, extinction and concentration. Thus concentration is absorption divided by the product of path and extinction. The rate of change of concentration (first derivative with respect to time of concentration is the rate of change of absorption divided by the product of path and extinction. If the rate of change of absorption is negative the rate of change of concentration is negative. Concentration is decreasing.